# Redirect database call to different db url based on type of query(Read, write, update) with Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-mysql

In an existing project, how can I implement a method using which I can redirect it different database(Write, Update & read) without modifying existing Django queries?

If I have 2 queries:

1. `MyModel.objects.get(name = "abc")`
   And
2. `MyModel.objects.create(name = "xyz")`

With database config as:

```py
DATABASES = {
       'read_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'read_db',
        'USER': 'read_db',
        'PASSWORD': 'read_db',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'write_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'write_db',
        'USER': 'write_db',
        'PASSWORD': 'write_db',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'update_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'update_db',
        'USER': 'update_db',
        'PASSWORD': 'update_db',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Want read_db to be called for query 1 & write_db for query 2

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Django's [Database Routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing). You can specify your `db_for_read` and `db_for_write` without having to change the queries.